# adding url on drilldown highchart

Tags: javascript

Adding URL on drilldown is not working, I'm not sure if my code is not valid.

```
                    drilldown: {
                        series: [
                        {"name": "Dec 2018", "id": "Dec 2018", "data": [["Ontime", 2, "ownURL":"show_all_gages.php?sel_company=ALL&mon1=&yr1=&mon2=&yr2=&sel_turnday=7&sel_type=inhousefieldservice&sel_vendor=&sel_month_year=1&sel_passfail=PASS"], ["Delayed", 1, "ownURL":"show_all_gages.php?sel_company=ALL&mon1=&yr1=&mon2=&yr2=&sel_turnday=7&sel_type=inhousefieldservice&sel_vendor=&sel_month_year=1&sel_passfail=FAIL"]]},{"name": "Jan 2019", "id": "Jan 2019", "data": [["Ontime", 6, "ownURL":"show_all_gages.php?sel_company=ALL&mon1=&yr1=&mon2=&yr2=&sel_turnday=7&sel_type=inhousefieldservice&sel_vendor=&sel_month_year=Dec 2018&sel_passfail=PASS"], ["Delayed", 2, "ownURL":"show_all_gages.php?sel_company=ALL&mon1=&yr1=&mon2=&yr2=&sel_turnday=7&sel_type=inhousefieldservice&sel_vendor=&sel_month_year=Dec 2018&sel_passfail=FAIL"]]} 
                        ]}
```

Comment: you can't use `key:value` in array `[]` use objects `{}` when you want to have` key` in this case `"ownURL"` for your values

Comment: Can you post your code too. This is only a json format you have posted. where you are facing the issue. post the code you had tried so far.